# How to sort these data based on some criteria in R

Tags: r

Here is a sample of my data :

```
 M<-read.table (text=" group    value   blue
    B   12  Y
    C   14  Y
    A   12  Y
    B   12  N
    C   10  Y
    A   7   Y
    B   6   Y

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to have a sum for each group based on the value group_by(group) or using aggregate. Next will look at blue; if it is a "Y", then I sum them based on each group. For example, A, both are Y, so A=19.  Now I can calculate p, i.e., 19/19*100.
Here is the outcome that I got it.

```
 group  value   P
    A   19  100
    B   30  60
    C   24  100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

M %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(P = 100 * sum(value[blue == "Y"])/sum(value),
            value = sum(value)) %>%
  select(1, 3, 2)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   group value     P
#>   <chr> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 A        19   100
#> 2 B        30    60
#> 3 C        24   100
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks- I am not sure when I applied your codes for my real data, I got NA for value and P. However when I applied @user18894435's codes, I don't get any error. Sorry if I am missing anything

Comment: @user330 perhaps there are NA values in your real data, in which case each `sum` requires an `na.rm = TRUE` in it?

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you and upvoted

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

M %>%
  count(group, blue, wt = value) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(N = sum(n), P = n[blue == 'Y'] / N * 100)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  group     N     P
  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 A        19   100
2 B        30    60
3 C        24   100
```

Answer (score 1):

'data.table' solution, assuming there are no NA's in `value`. If not so, add `na.rm = TRUE` to the sum-functions

```
library(data.table)
setDT(M)[, .(value = sum(value), P = 100 * sum(value[blue == "Y"]) / sum(value) ), keyby = .(group)]
#    group value   P
# 1:     A    19 100
# 2:     B    30  60
# 3:     C    24 100
```